# Using memcached for multiple projects

Tags: php, session, nginx, memcached

I'm using LEMP (Nginx, PHP-FPM) stack on my Ubuntu Server for about 10 PHP websites. Each website has it's own chroot'ed php pool, ubuntu user, sessions, logs and root folder.

Recently I got php session files inode problem: There were about 10 million session files collected in total and it took about 2 hours to only delete them.

Now what I want to do is, to switch session handling from file based to Memcached based so smooth that it will no affect on any website. I mean no code change will be required.

Main question for me is, if I change default session handling from file to memcached on my main php.ini may there be any collision between websites' session data? or is it dangerous? Any suggestions? I need a bit deeper explanation

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have same situation. 1 memcache server for few projects (websites). And yes, i store all sessions in memcache. To exclude collisions between projects (i store not only sessions in memcache) each project have an unique "prefix" for memcache access (set/delete). How its looks:

```
<?
  class ui { // or whatever
    public function __construct() {
      $this->memcache = new Memcached;
      if (!$this->memcache->addServer("127.0.0.1","1111")) 
            die('Something wrong.');
      $this->memcache_prefix = 'someUniQueForThisProjectString';
    }
    public function memset($var, $value) {
      return $this->memcache->set($this->memcache_prefix.$var, $value);
    }
    public function memdel($var) {
      return $this->memcache->delete($this->memcache_prefix.$var);
    }
  }
?>
```